# rail installation problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
C:\rubygems-1.3.7>gem install rails ruby-debug capistrano rspec ZenTest webrat  image_scie
nce mini_magick mechanize RedCloth  fastercsv piston sashimi ruport json newgem open4 rubi
gen --no-ri --no-rdoc
WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:
        http://rubygems.org/
        http://gems.rubyforge.org
        http://gems.rubyforge.org

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
Bulk updating Gem source index for: http://rubygems.org/
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    Error fetching remote gem cache: SocketError: getaddrinfo: no address associated with
hostname. (http://rubygems.org/yaml)
```

Keep getting the above error, tried other linked questions and google to no avail, please help!!

Thanks in advance

Will.

gems env :

```
C:\rubygems-1.3.7>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mswin32-60
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - C:/Users/Will/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org
```

Comment: it looks like something is wrong with your internet connection `no address associated with hostname` or your DNS connection. try `ping rubygems.org` from the command line

Comment: C:\rubygems-1.3.7>ping rubygems.org

Pinging rubygems.org [72.4.120.124] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 72.4.120.124: bytes=32 time=92ms TTL=51
Reply from 72.4.120.124: bytes=32 time=94ms TTL=51
Reply from 72.4.120.124: bytes=32 time=95ms TTL=51
Reply from 72.4.120.124: bytes=32 time=147ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for 72.4.120.124:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 92ms, Maximum = 147ms, Average = 107ms

Comment: I tried C:\rubygems-1.3.7>ping http://rubygems.org
Ping request could not find host http://rubygems.org. Please check the name and try again.  Could this be the problem, if so what file do I need to edit?

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of:

```
gem env
```

Have you tried updating your gem system?

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: gem env

C:\rubygems-1.3.7>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mswin32-60
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - C:/Users/Will/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000

Comment: - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org

Comment: Tried the update:

C:\rubygems-1.3.7>gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:
        http://rubygems.org

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
Bulk updating Gem source index for: http://rubygems.org/
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    Error fetching remote gem cache: SocketError: getaddrinfo: no address associated with
hostname. (http://rubygems.org/yaml)

Thanks for responding mate.

Answer (score 0):

rubygems.org has had network problems in the past day or so. It's probably just more of that and nothing on your end. Just be patient and keep trying.